# TFS Team Build: Deploy Azure Cloud Service

Tags: azure, tfs, tfsbuild, azure-devops, azure-cloud-services

I'm having some trouble deploying an Azure Web Service using the new Team Build that is available at Visual Studio Online. When the solution have been built successfully, the deployment task tries to find the CsPkg and the CsCfg, which fails.

How do I specify the "Path of CsPkg/CsCfg under the default artifact directory" that is required? Do I have to specify some MSBuild arguments?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `$(build.stagingDirectory)` variable in the `CsPkg`/`CsCfg` fields. This will be the root of your repo. Your binaries will be at some location under there. E.g. `$(build.stagingDirectory)\*.cspkg` and 
`$(build.stagingDirectory)\*.cscfg`

There's a huge list of built-in variables on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/vs/alm/Build/scripts/variables).

You may also have to build your cloud service project with the MSBuild argument `/t:Publish`

I just checked: If you use the "Cloud Service" deployment template, all of this stuff is automatically filled in for you, including the paths.